# js считает +1 год в дни рождения

Tags: javascript

Неправильно считает день рождения. т,е если сегодня 26 февраля 2019, а др стоит где-нибудь 10.10.2019., то он показывает 25 лет.

```js
    if(userInfo && userInfo.birthDay){
            let date = new Date(HexToSignedInt(userInfo.birthDay));
            let optionsTime = {
                year: 'numeric',
                month: '2-digit',
                day: '2-digit'
            };
            birthDay = date.toLocaleString('en-GB', optionsTime).replace(',', ' ');
            // years = this.calculateAge(date.getFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth() + 1, date.getUTCDate());
            years = this.calculateAge(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
        }
    
    
    
    calculateAge(year, month, day) {
        let currentDate = new Date();
        let currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
        let currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
        let currentDay = currentDate.getDate();
        // You need to treat the cases where the year, month or day hasn't arrived yet.
        let age = currentYear - year;
        // if (currentMonth < month) {
        if (currentDate < month) {
            return age;
        } else {
            if (currentDay >= day) {
                return age;
            } else {
                age--;
                return age;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Это что - if (currentDate < month) ?

Comment: *то он показывает 25 лет* - а сколько должно быть?

Comment: ну 24. День рождения же 10.10.1994, а сейчас 26.02.2019. А currentDate забыл закомментить, там был currentMonth

Comment: Ну извините, я не знаю, когда там у вас день рождения... Судя по вопросу, человек вообще ещё не родился.

Comment: была ошибка, говорю ж 10.10.1994 стоит др, короче он плюсует месяц, если др выставить на месяц вперед, типа 10.03.1994. то он считает правильно, но если  больше чем 1 месяц, то он считает неправильно

Comment: _А currentDate забыл закомментить, там был currentMonth_ - самое время раскомменить, нет? А то код неправильный, входные данные неправильные, как тут что понять?

Comment: О том, что в getMonth() январь это 0, а март это 2, тоже нужно помнить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логика сравнения должна быть простой:

1. Если текущий месяц меньше месяца в дате рождения - возраст равен разнице годов -1
2. в противном случае,

   1. если текущий день меньше дня в дате рождения - возраст  равен разнице годов-1
   2. иначе разнице годов

Пример в числах:

Дата рождения: 2000-02-10

1. Сегодня 2019-02-09, т.е. за день до:

   1. разница годов 2019-2000 = 19
   2. текущий месяц совпадает
   3. текущий день меньше дня в дате рождения, результат 19-1 = 18.
2. Сегодня 2019-02-10, т.е. день рождения сегодня

   1. разница годов 2019-2000 = 19
   2. текущий месяц совпадает
   3. текущий день не меньше дня в дате рождения, результат 19.
3. Сегодня 2019-02-11, т.е. день после

   1. разница годов 2019-2000 = 19
   2. текущий месяц совпадает
   3. текущий день не меньше дня в дате рождения, результат 19.
4. Сегодня 2019-01-09, т.е. на месяц раньше

   1. разница годов 2019-2000 = 19
   2. текущий месяц меньше - результат 19-1 = 18

Пример:

```js
function calculateAge(year, month, day) {
  let currentDate = new Date();
  let currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
  let currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
  let currentDay = currentDate.getDate();
  console.log(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay);
  console.log(year, month, day);
  // You need to treat the cases where the year, month or day hasn't arrived yet.
  let age = currentYear - year;
  if (currentMonth < month) {
    return age - 1;
  }
  return currentDay < day ? age - 1 : age;
}

console.log(calculateAge(2000, 1, 10));
console.log(calculateAge(2000, 1, 26));
console.log(calculateAge(2000, 1, 27));
console.log(calculateAge(2000, 2, 10));
```

Comment: (2000, 1, 10) - это какая дата?

Comment: @Эникейщик, 10 февраля 2000. (отсчет месяцев с 0)

Comment: @Grundy код дает неверный результат, я заменил 
currentDay < day ? age - 1 : age; и стало норм, спасибо.

Comment: @Oleksey, поправил код, с месяцами тоже проблема была

Comment: @Oleksey, добавил больше примеров

Comment: @Grundy а как установить дату раньше 1970, можно такое сделать?

Comment: @Oleksey, конечно можно, точно так же как и дату позже 1970. Откуда предположение, что так делать нельзя?

Comment: @Grundy у меня получается invalid date и мне сказали надо выводить строкой просто.

Comment: @Oleksey, стоит задать об этом отдельный вопрос, в котором привести, что и как ты вызываешь, что получаешь в ответ и что рассчитывал получить.

Answer (score 0):

@Oleksey зачем такие сложности?

```
const currentDate = new Date()
const birthDate = new Date('1994-10-10');
const MILLISECONDS_IN_YEAR = 31536000000;
const age = Math.floor((currentDate - birthDate ) / MILLISECONDS_IN_YEAR);
console.log(`Возраст: ${age}`);
Не учел високосные годы =(
```

или используя momentJS

```
const age = moment().diff(moment('1994-10-10'), 'year')
```

Comment: А определять возраст в годах через миллисекунды это, конечно, никакие не сложности :D Не говоря уже о том, что этот код в ряде случаев дает неправильный результат.

Comment: Может это конечно и проще, но оно дает неверный результат. возьмем сегодня (26.02.2019) скажем ДР 24.02.2014 дает 25 лет, так же как и 28.02.2014. Т.е. ДР проходит, а возраст не меняется. А проблема в том, что есть високосные годы, а константу вы заложили на 365 дней. (А если вы вдруг решите как то учесть високосные, то есть еще https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Comment: да, забыл про високосные годы

Comment: не мой код, дали поправить, а сам на стажировке.